# SublimeREPL 3 python is always closed

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am learning Python and i am using Sublime Text 3 as a Python's editor.
But now i have a little problem. I am trying to use SublimeRepl and i've watched so many tutorials how to use it, but when i have try to open python project with REPL it says me "repl closed". It always says that. Repl>Python works normally, but when i try to open something with it, it is always closed.

I also have made changes to *main.sublime-menu* like adding "-i" and replacing python (after cmd) with pythons path.

Also trying to reinstall sublime didn't help.

I tried running Python files on this code:

```
age = input("How old are you: ")
print(age)
```

That's it :). Thank's for any support.

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: What is the default python version on your computer?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Can you indicate what version of Python you are using? There have been issues that are related to the version.
Another suggestion is located [here](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/491).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `..\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\config\Python` directory.
2. Edit `Main.sublime-menu` file
3. Search for cmd": `["python", "-u", "$file_basename"]` and replace it with cmd": `["python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"]`. Value `"-i"` will make your python interactive.

Before doing those steps, to force sublime text build your python code in an interactive python shell, follow the steps below:

1. Go to `..\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` directory.
2. Create a new file named `SublimeREPL-python.sublime-build`
3. Copy this contain into it and save it:

```html
{ 
"target": "run_existing_window_command",
"id": "repl_python_run",
"file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu" 
}
```

4. Open sublime text, Go to: `Tools > Build system` and select: `SublimeREPL-python.sublime-build` instead of `Automatic`